# How to have haproxy log the entire request?

Tags: haproxy

I would like to log the entire request (obviously not for production).

To begin with I tried to record all headers (without knowing what they will be in advance).

In `haproxy.cfg` in the `frontend` section

```
    mode http
    option http-buffer-request
    declare capture request len 40000000
http-request capture ".*" id 0
#    log-format '{"srcIP":"%[src]","backend":"%s","bIP":"%si","bPORT":"%sp","method":"%[capture.req.method]","user-agent":"%[capture.req.hdr(1),json(utf8s)]","uri":"%[capture.req.uri]","body":"%[capture.req.hdr(0)]"}'
log-format '%[capture.req.hdr(0)]'
option dontlognull
```

But the `http-request capture ".*" id 0` is not accepted (neither is `http-request capture .* id 0`)

`error detected in frontend 'web_front_end' while parsing 'http-request capture' rule : unknown fetch`

Which I don't understand because from the [docs](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.0/configuration.html#4-http-request) it says that the format is `http-request capture <sample> [ len <length> | id <id> ]` where `<sample>` is an 'expression' (regular?).

Is there a simpler way to log everything in the request (and response too)?

Or how can I log all of the request headers without knowing what they will be?

Answer (score 2):

I use in general a different approach which is a bit more generic - network capture. In Linux you can use `tcpdump`, here is an example: `tcpdump -w network_capture.pcap -i eth0`. Then I open the capture in [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/).

You can use WireShark directly if you have a GUI in Linux, MacOS, Windows, etc.

Comment: Thanks - I had tried similar with TShark, but struggling with it being HTTPS, have you been able to work with encrypted traffic?  If yes then I will probably try to persevere that way.

Comment: The other problem I will face with this approach is that the traffic is from a 3rd party (a webhook actually) and so I have no way to get their encryption keys for the traffic (even if I could make the think work anyway)...

Comment: You can also use `strace -fys 1000 -p <haproxy_pid> -w trace.txt` then analyze the recorded file.